# Selenium automation with chromedriver leaves scoped_dir* folders on machine

Tags: selenium, automation, directory, selenium-chromedriver, space

I am executing automation tests with selenium and chromedriver on remote machines using selenium grid.

after updating chrome to Version 57.0.2987.133 and chromedriver to v2.28 we started experiencing failures. test profile folders named `scoped_dir*` are left behind after calling `driver.quit()` and very fast the disk space on the machines are full. shortly after the new v2.29 of chromedriver was published we updated all machines but still having this problem.

We have to delete the folders manually

Answer (score 1):

This issue ([644](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=644)) was fixed in chromedriver v2.30 (released in 2017).

(I ran into this question while researching why the new msedgedriver (v80) is exhibiting similar behavior.)

Comment: Yes, I am having the same issue with msedge. Did you find any solution? I am running selenium tests on team city and there are millions of files inside /BuildAgent/temp/buildTemp folder